Combining multiple columns in google sheet with different header
i have a google sheet that is connected to a google form,
there are multiple columns that i would like to combine to create a master data.
could you help me create a script for that? thank you.
so the google sheet looks like this...
original sheet
and i'm trying to make it to be like this.
expected result
Thank you in advance.
i tried searching the net for scripts that could do that but the closest one i found keeps getting an error.
so i basically i want the script to run everytime theres a new answer from the google form. and just add the new data in that format into the existing sheet. Thank you in advance.
add detail:
made a mistake earlier about the kind of output i wanted.
heres the default answer sheet once someone answered the google form.
original sheet
and then heres the output i was trying to come up with.
expected result

are you out for strictly script based solution OR a formula would suffice?! If its the latter as well, suggest you to share a test sheet showcasing your input and expected output(filled manually)

Related: Combine multiple columns on google sheet and create a new header for that combined column.

Use choosecols(), hstack(), byrow(), torow() and filter(). Choose Insert > Sheet and put this formula in cell A1 of the new sheet:
=let( 
  data, 'Form Responses 1'!A1:Q, 
  head, choosecols(data, 1), 
  body, choosecols(data, sequence(1, columns(B:P), 2)), 
  tail, choosecols(data, -2, -1), 
  table, hstack( 
    head, 
    byrow(body, lambda(row, single(torow(row, 1)))), 
    tail 
  ), 
  filter(table, len(head)) 
)

See
let(),
choosecols(),
sequence(),
hstack(),
byrow(),
torow()
and
filter().

Thank you for your response, I tried the formula and it worked. but i made a mistake on the output i wanted. I edited the picture above to show what kind of output i was expecting. thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only one question per post. Post a new question instead.
